# Expected response time of Continuous time Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I'm studying CTMC (Continuous Time Markov Chains). I came across the following slide

[image: CTMC]

I don't understand how they got

$M(t+h) = M(t) + \alpha h + M(t)\lambda h - M(t) \mu h +o(h)$

Could anyone please explain how to derive this expression for $M(t+h)$.

If I define $T(t)$ = Sojourn Time at $t$ and want to compute $N(t)=E(T(t))$

Then can I write $N(t)= M(t)/\lambda$ ?

How can I write a similar expression like $M(t+h)$ for $N(t+h)$?

**Update:** I found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772916/a-linear-growth-model-with-immigration) which is already answered but my second question about computing $E[N(t+h)]$ still holds.