# Linear rates Birth/Death Process with immigration

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, birth-death-process

Example 6.4 taken from S. M. Ross "Introduction to Probability Models", 10th edition.

> Let $X(t)$ denote the population size at time $t$ of a birth/death process with rates:
>
> $$
> \begin{split}
> \mu_n     &= n \mu             &\quad n\geq 1\\
> \lambda_n &= n \lambda+ \theta &\quad n\geq 0
> \end{split}
> $$
>
> Suppose that $X(0)=i$ and let $M(t) = E[X(t)]$
>   Consider $M(t+h)$, conditioning on $X(t)$ yields:
>   $$ M(t+h) = E[X(t+h)] = E[E[X(t+h)|X(t)]] $$
>
> Given the size of the population at time $t$ then, ignoring events with probability $o(h)$, the population at time $t+h$ will either increase by $1$ if a birth or an immigration occurs, decrease by $1$ if a death occurs or remain the same if neither occurs. That is:
>   \begin{equation}
> X(t+h) = \begin{cases}
> X(t)+1, & \text{with probability } [\theta+X(t)\lambda]h+o(h) \\
> X(t)-1, & \text{with probability } X(t)\mu h+o(h) \\
> X(t),   & \text{with probability } 1-[\theta+X(t)\lambda+X(t)\mu]h+o(h) \\
> \end{cases}
> \tag{1}
> \end{equation}
>
> Therefore:
>   $$ E[X(t+h)|X(t)] = X(t) + [\theta+X(t)\lambda-X(t)\mu]h +o(h) \tag{2}$$

The example goes on but my question is related to these lines. The question is: starting from the information on probabilities given in $(1)$ what are the steps to end at $(2)$. I clearly see that quantities in $(2)$ comes from $1$ but I don't understand the way in which they are combined. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The expectation is the sum of the values weighted by their probabilities. The three probabilities add to $1$ (as they must), and $X(t)$ occurs in all three values, so that yields the term $X(t)$. The remaining terms arise from the terms $\pm1$ in the values in the first two cases.

Comment: I understood your point but I still can't formalize the steps, can you write the steps down? I know that $E[X]= \sum_x xP(X=x)$ but from eq $1$ I don't understand the roles (values assumed) of $x$ and $P(X=x)$ in this particular case. Thanks

Comment: @Alfonse: The values $x$ are the three values to the right of the big brace in $(1)$: $X(t)+1$, $X(t)-1$ and $X(t)$. Their probabilities are the values written after them ("with probability ..."). So e.g. $P(X(t+h)=X(t)-1)\mid X(t))=X(t)\mu h+o(h)$.